Is it true that $2^{1/3}ζ\notin \Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3}) $?
I want to find a minimal polynomial of $2^{1/3}ζ$ over $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ where $ζ$ be premetive root of $x^3=1$.
$2^{1/3}ζ$ is a root of $X^2+2^{1/3}X+4^{1/3}$.
If I can prove $2^{1/3}ζ\notin \Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3}) $ , this quadratic polynomial is what we want.
I think I can prove we can find contradiction if there exists $a,b,c\in \Bbb{Q}$. such that $2^{1/3}ζ=a+b2^{1/3}+c4^{1/3}$.
But are there another simple way to prove this ?
Thank you for your good ideas.

For a field, $a\zeta\in K$ implies $a^{-1}\cdot (az)\in K$, so $\zeta\in K$. Here $a\in K$.

If $2^{\frac{1}{3}}\zeta \in \mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$, then $\zeta \in \mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$ which isn't true.

Oh, this is obvious because $\Bbb{Q}(ζ)/\Bbb{Q}$ is degree $2$ extension and $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})/\Bbb{Q}$ is degree 3 .

The reason is just this: the field has only real numbers, and $\zeta$ is not real.

@Dietrich Burde Cool. Scales have fallen from my eyes. Thank you.
